# pyqt5 qtablewdiget printing every column data separately

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a `qtablewidget` with 3 columns and 1 row in pyqt5. Now I want to get the value of every column separately and store that in a variable that I can print them back one by one. I do like this but it just prints the first column value

```
def PrintData(self):
    name = self.tableWidget.itemAt(self.tableWidget.currentColumn() , 0).text()
    email = self.tableWidget.itemAt(self.tableWidget.currentColumn(), 1).text()
    print(name)
    print(email)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve your items like so

```
name = [self.tableWidget.item(row, 0).text() for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount())]

email = [self.tableWidget.item(row, 1).text() for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount())]
```

.... etc

Comment: Glad it helped! If you think this sufficiently answers your question, feel free to mark it as accepted